# Tela branca no wp-admin no WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress

Olá galera estou com um problema no meu wordpress apenas colocando ONLINE em hospedagem que a tela do WP-ADMIN fica branca.
 **Ja tentei ligar o DEBUG mas não aparece nenhum erro, já fiz o upload 5x, ja excluiur todos os plugins e tentei e nada.**
Em local host fica normal.

Fiz toda a instalação do Wordpress com o IP e Banco de dados direto da hospedagem e criei o blog em localhost com tudo funcional mas quando joguei ele online o wp-admin fica com tela branca

Comment: Podes juntar uma imagem ou descrição mais completa do problema?

Comment: mas é só isso tela branca quando linko dominio/wp-admin

Comment: você importou o banco de dados? e você mudou a url do site?

Comment: Podes descrever como transferiste/instalaste o site?

Comment: não importei, eu ja coloquei por IP para evitar problema então o banco de dados está certo, sim mudei no wp_options certinho...

Comment: A base de dados permite acesso exterior?

Comment: eu instalei normalmente porem ocloquei o IP da hospedagem e criei corretamente e com sucesso todo o meu blog porem quando fui jogar o site online o wp-admin fica tela branca quando acesso

Comment: @Sergio sim permite ^^, mas está dando tela branca com o site ja online..

Comment: em localhost fica certinho o wp admin e site, mas quando joguei online na hospedagem ae fica dando tela branca no wp-admin

Comment: "eu instalei normalmente" é demasiado vago...

Comment: @Sergio fiz a instalação do wordpress colocando o banco de dados e ip da hospedagem e instalou corretamente, criei o site testei tudo em locahost e funciono 100% o meu blog. mas ae joguei agora o site via ftp online e o wp-admin fica dando tela branca.

Comment: Se colocar um `teste.php` na raiz do site com um `echo 'teste';`, o que acontece? Você só menciona wp-admin, mas não o que aparece no seu site.com.br...

Comment: Além de setar o debug no wp-config.php vc tem que ver as configurações do seu servidor PHP (procure o PHP.ini) e verificar que pode mostrar o erro. Também pode tentar ver os arquivos de log do PHP e ativar o log do WordPress. Então com a mensagem de erro nesses logs fica mais fácil resolver.

Comment: tente certificar que tens conexão a Base de dados, depois de confirmar, confirme que alteraste na tabela wp_options os dados de localhost pelos novos(correspondentes ao servidor). E caso continue tente www.teulink.com/index.php/wp-admin.  Se conseguires acesso tente ir a settings e trocar os links provavelmente ainda nao tenha actualiazido

Comment: Antes de fazer qualquer coisa, tente desfazer o que vc fez por ultimo. Como vc já desinstalou os plugins, e não funcionou. Tente tirar o .htaccess da raiz, mas faça um backup antes. O front do site está funcionando? Veja os últimos arquivos alterados no WP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser também que você esteja vendo a tela branca porque esgotou o limite de memória do php do seu servidor. Isso pode ser causado por algum plugin ou thema que consome muita memoria do php.

As vezes também pode significar que há um problema com o seu servidor de hospedagem web. Então já que o problema pode ser causado por uma série de fatores, isso pode exigir talvez uma grande quantidade de soluções diferentes.

Para aumentar o limite de memoria do php, vá até o php.ini e altere a seguinte linha:

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

Provavelmente esteja em 64 ou 128, altere para 512.

Caso não esteja usando php.ini em sua hospedagem, ou seja está usando o  Apache Handler, o PHP está em modulo do Apache e será necessário criar um arquivo .htaccess e colocar o seguinte valor:

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
```